# Standard way to duplicate a file's permissions

Tags: command-line, unix, chmod, posix

I am trying to find a standard POSIX way to duplicate one file's permissions to another file. On a GNU system this is easy:

```
[alexmchale@bullfrog ~]$ ls -l hardcopy.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexmchale users 2972 Jul  8 20:40 hardcopy.1
---------- 1 alexmchale users 2824 May 14 13:45 hardcopy.4
[alexmchale@bullfrog ~]$ chmod --reference=hardcopy.1 hardcopy.4
[alexmchale@bullfrog ~]$ ls -l hardcopy.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexmchale users 2972 Jul  8 20:40 hardcopy.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexmchale users 2824 May 14 13:45 hardcopy.4
```

Unfortunately, the --reference flag to chmod is a non-standard option. So that is out for my purposes. I would prefer it to be a one-liner, but that's not necessary. Ultimately, it does need to be in POSIX sh syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One temptation is to parse `ls`. [Avoid that temptation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

The following seems to work, however it is full of teh Kluge. It relies on `cp` retaining the permissions of the target file. For this demo, the file "template" must not already exist.

- Copy the file with the permissions you want to a ***new*** file
- Copy the file that you want to change to the file created in the previous step
- Remove the original file that you want to change
- Rename the intermediate file to the name of the file to be changed

Demo:

```
$ echo "contents of has">has
$ echo "contents of wants">wants
$ chmod ug+x has     # just so it's different - represents the desired permissions
$ cp has template
$ cat has
contents of has
$ cat wants
contents of wants
$ cat template
contents of has
$ ls -l has wants template
-rwxr-xr-- 1 user user 16 2010-07-31 09:22 has
-rwxr-xr-- 1 user user 16 2010-07-31 09:23 template
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 18 2010-07-31 09:22 wants
$ cp wants template
$ ls -l has wants template
-rwxr-xr-- 1 user user 16 2010-07-31 09:22 has
-rwxr-xr-- 1 user user 18 2010-07-31 09:24 template
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 18 2010-07-31 09:22 wants
$ cat template
contents of wants
$ rm wants
$ mv template wants
$ ls -l has wants
-rwxr-xr-- 1 user user 16 2010-07-31 09:22 has
-rwxr-xr-- 1 user user 18 2010-07-31 09:24 wants
$ cat has
contents of has
$ cat wants
contents of wants
```

Comment: Now that's an interesting approach. I'm going to test this out and see how well it works against various servers. It seems to me like it'll do the trick.

Comment: @Alex: make sure to test it with file ownership, too, if that's a concern.

Comment: The first cp command, `cp has template`, should use `cp -p` to preserve the mode and ownership attributes.

Comment: @mernst: That's only necessary for the first `cp` if the owner/group of the file (e.g. "user") is different from the one doing the copying (e.g. root).

Comment: @Dennis Willamson: OK, but that is a possibility and I don't see any downside to using `cp -p` there.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the `stat` command to get the file permission :

- Mac OS X (BSD) syntax :

  > chmod `stat -f %A fileWithPerm` fileToSetPerm
- Linux syntax (not sure) :

  > chmod `stat -c %a fileWithPerm` fileToSetPerm

The **`** symbol is a backquote.

Comment: I don't think `stat` is required by POSIX. It's often not available.

Comment: stat (command line) is not POSIX, and is not portable. Dennis++

Answer (score 1):

ACL utilities *getfacl* and *setfacl* can be used for this purpose, but I don't know if this POSIX compliant enough. Works at least in FreeBSD 8.0 and Linux, but on the other hand one might have to install the ACL utilities.

From the man-page:

```
getfacl file1 | setfacl -b -n -M - file2
Copy ACL entries from file1 to file2.
```

I think getfacl and setfacl can operate also standard file permissions in addition to ACL's.

Comment: ACLs and such are defined by POSIX is implementation-specific, so it's not required for compliance.

Answer (score 1):

`cp -p` will preserve file permissions.

Comment: That's why the technique in my answer (of *not* using `-p`) works for what the OP wants which is to duplicate permissions for a *different* file, not a *duplicate* of the file.

Answer (score 0):

One portable, straightforward way is not a standard utility - you would need to
call stat() on the templatefile,  then chmod() on the destination file(s). This means using a language like C or another widely used language like perl.

The file access permissions are specified  in  the struct stat st_mode member  by  the
0007777 bits.  Dennis' solution is correct, if a bit heavy on I/O, so for really big files it may fail:

```
cp has template
```

Consider this not-ready-for-production example:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

mode_t 
getperm(const char *template_file)
{
    struct stat st;
    if(stat(template_file, &st)==-1)
    {
       perror("Cannot stat file");
       exit(1);
    }
    return st.st_mode;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
    mode_t mode=getperm(argv[1]);
    int i=0;
    for(i=2; argv[i]!=NULL; i++)    
    {
       if(chmod(argv[i], mode)==-1)
          fprintf(stderr, "Permissions failed on %s:\n\t%s\n",
              argv[i], strerror(errno));
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution has been:

```sh
# Duplicate with permissions the file having the desired attributes.
cp -p attribute_src dest

# Truncate it, concatenating the desired content over it.
cat content_src > dest

# For a final touch, restore the original timestamps.
touch -r content_src dest
```

If your filesystem supports shallow copy you can avoid all the initial wasted POSIX-compliant I/O. For example, on macOS `cp⁠-c` will use clonefile(2) and return immediately.